# Restyle whole App UI on event - What is the best approach?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is mostly a pattern/design question with the following setup:

My app has a different styling during day/night, which includes:

- background images
- font sizes and colors
- ui element positioning
- button images
- etc...

The [UIAppearance Proxy Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html) is used as much as possible, as well as a storyboard.
Nevertheless much of the styling is done in the specific Views viewDidLoad methods, which has to be updated as well.

**The Problem:**

When the app is active during the switch from day to night and vice versa all newly created UI elements are styled according to the new setting, as expected, but the elements, which were already present during the previous setting remain unstyled. How can i trigger a restyle on all UI elements?

**Ideas:**

- Can i somehow trigger a complete UI redraw? (including calling each views viewDidLoad?)
- do i have to move all my styling from the viewDidLoad methods to layoutSubviews and call layoutIfNeeded?
- is there any more conveniant way?

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick Google search and found this:

```
// Update UIAppearance...

NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
    for (UIView *view in window.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        [window addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

... from
http://snipplr.com/view/75259/refresh-uiappearance-after-application-loaded/

It quite effectively reloads your entire view hierarchy. You'll need to put that somewhere that's triggered at specific time intervals.

Hope it works for you =]

Comment: i just tested it, but sadly doesn't work. I guess the reason is that this only refreshes the styling by UIAppearance? I have plenty of styling in my viewControllers viewDidLoad methods, as UIAppearance doens't work for all properties. Ill update the question to make this clear